# saving text files to .npy file

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, for-loop, glob

I have many text files in a directory with numerical extension(example: `signal_data1.9995100000000001,signal_data1.99961` etc)

The content of the files are as given below

signal_data1.9995100000000001

```
-1.710951390504200198e+00
 5.720409824754981720e-01
 2.730176313110273423e+00
```

signal_data1.99961

```
-6.710951390504200198e+01
 2.720409824754981720e-01
 6.730176313110273423e+05
```

I just want to arrange the above files into a single .npy files as

```
-1.710951390504200198e+00,5.720409824754981720e-01, 2.730176313110273423e+00
-6.710951390504200198e+01,2.720409824754981720e-01, 6.730176313110273423e+05
```

So, I want to implement the same procedure for many files of a directory.

I tried a loop as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
for file in glob.glob(./signal_*):
    np.savez('data', file)
```

However, it does not give what I want as depicted above. So here I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of achieving it:

```
import os 

dirPath = './data/' # folder where you store your data

with os.scandir(dirPath) as entries:
    output = ""
    for entry in entries: # read each file in your folder
        dataFile = open(dirPath + entry.name, "r")
        dataLines = dataFile.readlines()
        dataFile.close()
        for line in dataLines:
            output += line.strip() + " " # clear all unnecessary characters & append
        output += '\n' # after each file break line
    writeFile = open("a.npy", "w") # save it
    writeFile.write(output)
    writeFile.close()
```

Comment: error: OSError: Failed to interpret file a.npy as a pickle, however running process going good

Comment: Okk, little bit mistake i did, i need comma separated output, please have a look my updated output

Comment: Whops, I made a formatting error.

Comment: As you can see, I'm concatenating each line to one output string. You can modify it however you want.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, once you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.loadtxt()` and `np.save()`:

```
a = np.array([np.loadtxt(f) for f in sorted(glob.glob('./signal_*'))])
np.save('data.npy', a)
```